# SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos5, wifi

When I am starting wlan0 it shows me the following error:

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such file or directory
```

I should install firmware, How to determine which firmware do I need?

How to determine Wifi card driver name(or module name)?

One person tells me that I should install :iwl5000-firmware-8.24.2.12-1.elrepo.noarch.rpm
package but is this package for me?

Please help...My OS is CentOS 5.

Also what is firmware for?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `lspci`, `lsusb` or `dmidecode` to find out what make your wireless card is. Once you know that you should only be a Google search away from the correct drivers (or post here and we can help you further).

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a lot easier than Xiol suggests.  Most drivers that need firmware will write the name of the file, and in some cases the URL to a helpful webpage, directly to `dmesg`.  So all you should have to do is insert your driver, run `dmesg`, and look at the last few lines of output -- the answer should be right there.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge with us.I will mention your advice next time when i will have any problem:)