# ifconfig not showing wlan0

Tags: networking, virtualbox, wlan, adapter, kali-linux

Not able to see wlan0 on executing the command ifconfig:

The output on executing the command `ifconfig` is

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe1f:3076  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:1f:30:76  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6  bytes 1430 (1.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 29  bytes 2699 (2.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8  bytes 396 (396.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 396 (396.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

On executing the command `ifconfig -a`

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe1f:3076  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:1f:30:76  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8  bytes 2080 (2.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 31  bytes 3084 (3.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8  bytes 396 (396.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 396 (396.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:67:c6:4c:0a:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Then I tried to execute the command `ifconfig wlan0 up` it gives me the following error

`SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such file or directory`

I am using a wireless adapter

Name: Leoxsys LEO-HG150N 150Mbps Wireless USB Wi-Fi Adapter LAN Card with External Antenna

Wifi Chip Set: Ralink

I am using Kali-Linux in my virtual box

How to resolve the error please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: check this one https://serverfault.com/questions/293401/siocsifflags-no-such-file-or-directory ? Mostly os don't know about your driver, check the driver and install it to make it work.

Comment: when you set ip address on the interface, which in this case is wlan0 it will show up in the config result. if there is DHCP in your network then try "dhclient wlan0"